# Label String not being Set

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

This is for a Mac application, 'setText' is for iOS

I usually stuff all the code in the AppDelegate class but am trying to change this and I think this is why I am having trouble with something so basic.

I have made a new NSObject class called Calculate, and have created a Label and TextField. I have connected the Label to the Calculate class as an outlet called 'summaryLabel'.

In the implementation class I then set the label as so:

```
[summaryLabel setStringValue:@"TEST"];
```

Nothing happens!

I've no idea why but like i said I'm experimenting with different classes so I'm sure something's not joined up correctly. Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: Did you try to log the label? Can you provide a bit more code?

Comment: Where in the implementation are you trying to set the value, where is the code around this?

Comment: @JohannesLumpe I logged the label id and it returns null

Comment: Then it seems like your wiring is incorrect. You might want to double check that. And can you please post more code? your property for the label, and the surrounding code of the portion where you want to set the text?

Comment: You didn't connect what you thought you connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have two instances of your `Calculate` class.  You may have instantiated one in the NIB, which is how you've connected outlets.  Then you may be instantiating another in code using something like `[[Calculate alloc] init]`.  This is a different object.  Because it's not the one from the NIB, its outlets aren't connected to anything.

You want to have one instance.  If it really needs to be connected to things from the NIB, then it typically needs to be in the NIB.  (The NIB can have some proxy objects, like File's Owner, which are not *instantiated* in the NIB but you can connect them up to things and when the NIB is loaded those connections will connect to the real objects.)

If you also need a way to refer to the instance in the NIB, then you need an outlet from something else, possibly your app delegate, to that instance.

---

Update:

OK. So, you have a Calculate object in the NIB. That's a real "freeze-dried" object. When the NIB is loaded, that object is reconstituted and its connections are set up.

You also, separately, instantiate a `Calculate` object in code by doing something like `[[Calculate alloc] init]`, right? That's creating a separate object. It's not the one in the NIB and the connections you set up in the NIB don't affect it. So, its `summaryLabel` instance variable is just `nil`.

You need to pick one way of instantiating the object and stick to it:

Option 1) You stick with the `Calculate` object in the NIB. So, remove the part in your code where you alloc and init a new one. Instead, just reference the existing one that was created when the NIB was loaded. You need a reference to that. So, create an outlet on your app delegate to point to it and connect that in the NIB.

Option 2) You stick with the `Calculate` object you create in code. So, remove the one from your NIB. The object you created in code doesn't have a connection to the label because it's not from the NIB. So, you have to set up the connection to the label in code, just like you created it in code. You'll need a reference to the label. You can add an outlet to the app delegate and connect it to the label. Then your app delegate can do `calculateObject.summaryLabel = summaryLabel;` to tell the `Calculate` object that it has created about the label.

Comment: i didn't think i was instantiating the NIB, in my App Delegate class I do instantiate the Calculate class and run a method from it. It is within that method that I am setting the text of the label. Does that help at all? Thanks for your response!

Comment: You said "I have connected the Label to the Calculate class as an outlet called 'summaryLabel'." If there's no `Calculate` object in the NIB, what does that mean? How did you connect `summaryLabel`? If it's in code, then update your question to show that code.

Comment: There is a Calculate object in the Nib and I have attached the label to it, I don't understand what I've done wrong

Comment: fantastic, makes perfect sense, just one last question, option 1 seems preferable to me, but if I don't create the object in the NIB, I'm unable to connect to the outlets to my Calculate class, how do I resolve this? I really appreciate your help, thanks

Comment: I answered that already in Option 2. You don't use outlets, as such, just properties, and the code which creates the object is also responsible for giving it access to the label. Alternatively, it can give it access to itself and it gets at the label through that object.